# Filesystem connector produces no output & streamEnvironment.executes() throws "no operators defined"

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I have following code that wants to write the data generated with datagen to a file, but when I run the application, no target directory is created, and no data is written.

When I add `env.execute()` at the end of the code, it complains that `No operators defined in streaming topology. Cannot execute.`

I would ask how to make the application work, thanks.

```
test("insert into table") {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    env.setParallelism(1)
    val tenv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env)
    val ddl =
      """
      create temporary table abc(
       name STRING,
       age INT
      ) with (
        'connector' = 'datagen'
      )
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.executeSql(ddl)

    val sql =
      """
        select * from abc
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    val sinkDDL =
      s"""
      create temporary table xyz(
       name STRING,
       age INT
      ) with (
       'connector' = 'filesystem',
       'path' = 'D:\\${System.currentTimeMillis()}-csv' ,
       'format' = 'csv'

      )
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.executeSql(sinkDDL)

    val insertInSQL =
      """
      insert into xyz
      select name, age from abc
      """.stripMargin(' ')

    tenv.executeSql(insertInSQL)


//    env.execute()


  }
```

Comment: could you clarify which version of Flink is the code relying on?

Comment: Thanks @svend. I am using Flink 1.12.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have UDF in table execution, see

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/table/functions/udfs.html#table-functions

You could see the example, write the function and insert it into your sql pipeline, this works as the "operator" in your error msg.

Comment: Thanks @litchy, but I don't think I have to write a function for such a simple and basic scenario.

Comment: @Tom Then you have to use the built-in function, like `print()` is a built-in sink. I do not know any, but you can just define the funtion `def fun(val v) = return v`.

Comment: Thanks @litchy, looks I get your point, you mean that I should provide a stream operation in the pipeline, so that makes `env.execute` happy?

Comment: Yes, thanks @litchy, it works.Kind of inconvenience, though.

Answer (score 1):

I think it actually works, just not *when* we think it does :)

I've tested this with the [Blink planner in Flink 1.12](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/#tab_Blink_Planner_1):

```
"org.apache.flink" %% "flink-table-planner-blink" % flinkVersion % "provided"
```

Calling `env.execute()` on the `StreamingEnvironment` at the end is actually *not* required, since each `.executeSql()` earlier in the program are already submitting asynchronous jobs. The sink in your code then gets attached to one of those jobs and not with the job that `env.execute()` would launch (which in this case is an empty job, triggering the error you mention). I found a clue about that in [this response on the mailing list](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Flink-1-11-SQL-error-No-operators-defined-in-streaming-topology-Cannot-execute-td37380.html#message37413).

When I run the code in the question (with the Blink planner, and adapting the output to `'path' = '/tmp/hello-flink-${System.currentTimeMillis()}-csv'` on my host), I see several *hidden* files being progressively being created. I'm guessing they are similarly being hidden on your Windows host (files starting with a `.` below mean hidden on Linux):

```
ls -ltra /tmp/hello-flink-1609574239647-csv
total 165876
drwxrwxrwt 40 root  root      12288 Jan  2 08:57 ..
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 134217771 Jan  2 08:59 .part-393f5557-894a-4396-bdf9-c7813fdd1d75-0-0.inprogress.48863a2b-f022-401b-95e3-659ec4920162
drwxrwxr-x  2 svend svend      4096 Jan  2 08:59 .
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend  35616014 Jan  2 08:59 .part-393f5557-894a-4396-bdf9-c7813fdd1d75-0-1.inprogress.3412bcb0-d30d-43be-819b-1acf26a0a8bb
```

What's happening is simply that the rolling policy of the [FileSystem SQL connector](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/table/connectors/filesystem.html#rolling-policy) is by default waiting much longer before committing the files.

If you start your code from the IDE, you can adapt the creation of the environment as follows (would normally be done in `conf/flink-conf.yaml`):

```
  val props = new Properties
  props.setProperty("execution.checkpointing.interval", "10000")  // 10000 ms
  val conf = ConfigurationUtils.createConfiguration(props)
  val fsEnv = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironment(1, conf)
```

and use a small file size in the output connector:

```
      create temporary table xyz(
       name STRING,
       age INT
      ) with (
       'connector' = 'filesystem',
       'path' = '/tmp/hello-flink-${System.currentTimeMillis()}-csv' ,
       'format' = 'csv',
       'sink.rolling-policy.file-size' = '1Mb'
```

And CSV files should now be committed much faster:

```
ls -ltra hello-flink-1609575075617-csv
total 17896
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048669 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-0
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048644 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-1
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048639 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-2
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048676 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-3
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048680 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-4
-rw-rw-r--  1 svend svend 1048642 Jan  2 09:11 part-a6158ce5-25ea-4361-be11-596a67989e4a-0-5
```

Comment: Thanks @svend for the great help! I will try